# Another can't remote mysql in gcloud

Tags: mysql, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I've gone through the basics, bind_address, Google's Firewall, ufw shows inactive but I can't even telnet to the machine on the mysql port.I'm trying to get spotfire to use our db directly just to test it out.

The mysql db is on a vm instance in Google Cloud.  The server can of course work with the db no problem, any external connections don't go through with this error:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '' (119)

Telnet says this:

> Connecting To ...Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306: Connect failed

I'm sure I'm missing something, any help will be awesome.

Comment: Please edit your post for us to help you, include what is your objective, what have you done, any documents or reference that you are following, your configuration and error that you encountered. Are you using Cloud SQL for Mysql or Mysql in Compute Engine?

Comment: Any thoughts?Thx,jake

Comment: Figured it out, the tags are how gcloud figures out what firewall rules to apply.

Comment: you can post it as an answer to help the others in case they will have the same problem.